# Match all code between two HTML tags using REGEX

Tags: html, regex, dreamweaver, replace

I'm looking for a greedy RegEx match to replace all text in a number of HTML files between `</title>` and `</head>` (I've combined loads of JavaScript files to minimize the number of http requests).

I've googled it but the majority of the solutions don't seem to work for me. (Which naturally leads me to assume that i'm wrong)

This is my current expression which doesn't seem to work:-

```
</title>([^<]*)</head>
```

I'm using Dreamweaver 8 search and replace.

Between the two tags there are multiple includes for various javascript files for example:-
     which vary on a page by page basis.

I want to replace everything between those two tags in all pages with a consistant list of CSS / JavaScript inclues.

Comment: What programming language / platform are you using?

Comment: @Adam add some example , i read three time, do you want to convert whole html in plain text?

Comment: Sorry guys, edited original post with more info.

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Lieven The OP is using dreamweaver

Comment: @NullUserException: I wasn't referring to the question but to the answer. As Tomalak mentioned it in this answer too, it could fail. Using a regex could be appropriate for a one time job but I wouldn't use it in code that's meant to last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If DreamWeaver regex supports look-ahead assertions:

```
</title>((?:(?!</head>)[\s\S])*)</head>
```

The usual warning "don't work on HTML with regex, this will fail at some point" applies. The points where this would fail could be:

```
<script>var str = "something that contains </head>";<script>
```

or

```
<!-- a comment that refers to </head> -->
```

among other constellations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like http://www.regextester.com/ ? You could test your regex live?

There are other approaches you could take to 'test' your case.

Comment: I managed to get it through the tester. However, the usual limitation is that I can't test with the multiple lines of code to the extent that they vary within the pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if i consider you are using php as you are looking for regex
//regex : '#\<\title\>(.+?)\<\/head\>#s'
//in php

    $content_processed = preg_replace_callback(
      '#\<\title\>(.+?)\<\/head\>#s',
      create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return htmlentities($matches[1]);'
      ),
      $content
    );

// this will return content between the tag
```

Comment: He is trying to do this in Dreamweaver (search & replace) not php

Comment: Hi Japan Pro,

I'm not using PHP, I'm just using the default Find + Replace functionality in Dreamweaver. I've tried putting in the following combinations since you posted but to no avail:-
1. #\<\title\>(.+?)\<\/head\>#s
2.    <\title\>(.+?)\<\/head\>
3.    <\title>(.+?)</head>

Comment: @Adam: Try `</title>` instead of `<\title>`