# Remove html tags around text which includes a new line

Tags: html, regex, replace

I have tags as follows in a .html file:

```
<td>
<P CLASS="abc">
hello</P>
</td>
```

I want to remove the `<P>` tags around the text and also remove the new line character after the first `<P>` tag, so that I only get the following text.

```
<td>
hello
</td>
```

The files are on a Linux server, so if anyone has any Linux methods for this, I'm interested. I can access the files also with Notepad++ which allows regular expressions for Find/Replace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618839/match-all-code-between-two-html-tags-using-regex?rq=1

Comment: If there is `<span>` around text, does it must be removed too (like any other tag)? If so, than `<td>` also must be removed

Comment: do you need to this on document load, or just manually on the server? If document load I would just use jquery, if manually, I would use sublime text's multiple selection features.

Comment: I need to keep the <td></td> tags, I'm unsure what you mean about the <span> tags.  I need this change made manually on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**  by regex `<p[^>]*>[\n\t\r]*|<\/p[^>]*>`

In notepad++ replace what `<p[^>]*>[\n\t\r]*|<\/p[^>]*>`  and replace with  (blank)

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU9vZ1/2)

**Update for next requirement:**

`(<td>[\s\S]*?)<P[^>]*>[\n\t\r]*([^>]+)<\/P>`  replace with `$1$2`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU9vZ1/3)

Comment: Hi, that does remove the tags in question, unfortunately, I have other <P></P> tags outside <TD></TD> tags, which I want to keep, but it also removes them.